# Search Array of Objects From Array of Objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects:

```
var objArray1 = [{'name':'abc', 'phone':'0333'}, 
                {'name':'xyz', 'phone':'0334'},
                {'name':'fgfh', 'phone':'0999'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0666'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0444'} 
               ]

var objArray2 = [{'name':'abc', 'mobile':'0333'}, 
                {'name':'xyz', 'mobile':'0334'},
                {'name':'fgfh', 'mobile':'0999'} 
               ]
```

I want to search index **phone** of `objArray1` from `objArray2`.

If matches i want that **object** of `objArray1` to be pushed in `existing` array, if no matches then push that object in `joiners` array.

Here is what i am trying to do.

```
objArray1.forEach(function(item){
    if (objArray2.indexOf(item.phone) < 0) {
        joiners.push(item)
    }else{
        existing.push(item)
    }
})
```

Above code is not working and putting all objects of `objArray1` into joiners.

Current Result:

```
joiners = [{'name':'abc', 'phone':'0333'}, 
                {'name':'xyz', 'phone':'0334'},
                {'name':'fgfh', 'phone':'0999'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0666'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0444'} 
               ]
```

Wanted Result:

```
joiners = [{'name':'abc', 'phone':'0666'},
           {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0444'} 
          ]
```

And after that i want to check **vise versa** and make an array of leavers if `any object of objArray2` do not exist in `objArray1`.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check existence using [**Array#some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function. It returns `true` if the condition is satisfied, otherwise `false`. `indexOf` is checking by comparing the references, because you have different objects, you will always get `false` in the `if` statement.

I have changed a bit the code in the `forEach` function

```js
const objArray1 = [
    {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0333'}, 
    {'name':'xyz', 'phone':'0334'},
    {'name':'fgfh', 'phone':'0999'},
    {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0666'},
    {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0444'}];

const objArray2 = [ 
    {'name':'abc', 'mobile':'0333'}, 
    {'name':'xyz', 'mobile':'0334'},
    {'name':'fgfh', 'mobile':'0999'}];
                
const joiners = [];
const existing = [];

objArray1.forEach(item => 
    objArray2.some(i => i.mobile === item.phone) ? 
    joiners.push(item) : existing.push(item));

console.log(joiners);
console.log(existing);
```

Comment: You know what I'm gonna say.

Comment: Worked with a minor tweak in condition. According to my need.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table and use it as condition for pushing.

```js
var objArray1 = [{ name: 'abc', phone: '0333' }, { name: 'xyz', phone: '0334' }, { name: 'fgfh', phone: '0999' }, { name: 'abc', phone: '0666' }, { name: 'abc', phone: '0444' }],
    objArray2 = [{ name: 'abc', mobile: '0333' }, { name: 'xyz', mobile: '0334' }, { name: 'fgfh', mobile: '0999' }],
    joiners = [],
    existing = [],
    hash = Object.create(null);

objArray2.forEach(function (item) { hash[item.mobile] = true; });

objArray1.forEach(function(item) {
    (hash[item.phone] ? existing : joiners).push(item);
});

console.log(joiners);
console.log(existing);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You know what I'm gonna say.